# Select List of Integers as Collection inside another result Map in Mybatis

Tags: collections, mybatis

I want to select Collection of Integers as Collection inside Result Map in Mybatis. I am unable to figure out a way for this.

Result class is

```
class Mapping {
private String name;
private List<Integer> ids;
}
```

Mybatis is as follows:

```
<resultMap id="mapping" type="some.package.Mapping">
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <collection property="ids" column="id" javaType="java.util.List" ofType="java.lang.Integer" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getMapping" resultMap="mapping">
        SELECT name, id
        FROM mapping
    </select>
```

This code in not working out for me.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 10):

To get a list of Integers in a single resultMap you can use:

```
<id property="name" column="name"/>
<collection property="ids" ofType="Integer">
    <result column="id"/>
</collection>
```

A nested select would also work, but it will execute N+1 queries, which may be [a performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue).

Answer (score 0):

mybatis do not know how to select id as id list.
you can use nested select

```
<collection property="ids" column="name" select="findIdByName" />

<select id="findIdByName" resultType="int">
        SELECT id
        FROM mapping where name = #{name}
    </select>
```